# I would like to update Listview cell only once

Tags: javafx

I would like to update Listview cell only once, but it updates everytime if i click the listview or scroll down the listview.

```
ListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<JSONObject>, ListCell<JSONObject>>(){

                @Override
                public ListCell<JSONObject> call(ListView<JSONObject> param) {

                    ListCell<JSONObject> cell = new ListCell<JSONObject>() {

                       protected void updateItem(JSONObject t, boolean bln) {

                           super.updateItem(t, bln);

                            if (t != null) {
                            // here was my code updating the cell    

                            }                     
                        }
                    };
                    return cell;
                }                          
        });
```

Is there any way to update the cell only once?

Comment: No, of course not. The whole point of a `ListView` is that it reuses cells when you scroll. The purpose of the `updateItem()` method is to update the cell when it is reused to display a different item (or otherwise changes, e.g. if its selected state changes). If it didn't update, it wouldn't display the correct items.

Comment: sounds like you need to read a decent tutorial or at least the api doc on Cell (and subclasses) and/or the virtualized controls that are using them